# Rails - no action in controller, but I keep passing test. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I wrote a basic test to ensure pages and titles are rendered as expected.

**static_pages_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should_get_contact" do
    get :contact
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact"
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/contact'

end
```

**contact.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Contact")%>

<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
  Some text.
</p>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
  ...
</head>
<body>

  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my **static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

As you notice there is no "contact" action so I expected test not to pass, whilst I keep getting green light.

```
davide@davidell:~/Desktop/app/sample_app$ bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 62452

# Running:

....

Finished in 0.194772s, 20.5369 runs/s, 41.0737 assertions/s.

4 runs, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Why? What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your answers, and happy new year :)

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra - thanks a lot! it makes sense! write an answer so I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better or for worse, this is one of the various "features" exposed by Rails as part of the convention over configuration approach. In my experience, this specific feature is mostly an unwanted side effect.

If your request matches a route and there is a template for that route matching the controller and the request format, then Rails will pretend the action to be defined as a simple empty method in the controller.

In your case, because you created the `contact.html.erb` template and you created a route that matches to the `#contact` action, this is equivalent to the same controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```